# %lu and %u both give me warnings....

Tags: ios, xcode, nsuinteger

Hi I get this warning when using %lu:

"format specifies type unsigned long but the argument has type unsigned int."

then when i replace to %u: the warning changes to:

"format specifies type unsigned int but the argument has type unsigned long."

here is my code:

```
NSString *viewName_ = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myGreatView%lu", currentTagLoadedOnView-99];
```

where currentTagLoadedOnView:

```
NSUInteger currentTagLoadedOnView;
```

any help greatly appreciated....

Comment: I checked with `%u`. I didn't get any warning !!! Which compiler you are using ?

Comment: @MidhunMP If you use `%u`, it won't give warning but if you use `%lu`, it will give warning as asked in question.

Comment: @Mani: I didn't say that, `%lu` not giving warning. I checked both control statement, but in my Xcode I didn't get warning for %u (Tested in gcc & llvm, also checked in Xcode 4 & Xcode 5)

Comment: Xcode 5.1 (5B130a) LLVM 5.1 (i only got the warnings after updating to Xcode 5.1 today...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try any one of the below

1) Use both as `unsigned int`

```
NSString *viewName_ = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myGreatView%u", currentTagLoadedOnView-99];
```

and declare currentTagLoadedOnView as `NSUInteger currentTagLoadedOnView;`

2) type cast to unsigned long

```
NSString *viewName_ = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myGreatView%lu", (unsigned long) currentTagLoadedOnView-99];
```

and declare currentTagLoadedOnView as `NSUInteger currentTagLoadedOnView;`

3) Defined unsinged long as both

```
NSString *viewName_ = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myGreatView%lu", (unsigned long) currentTagLoadedOnView-99];
```

and declare currentTagLoadedOnView as `unsigned long currentTagLoadedOnView;`

**Note:** Your warning will disappear if you use 64-bit architecture only(make changes to consistent data type) or 32-bit only(no change). If you use `Standard architecture(including 64-bit)`, it will give this warning.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what architecture I m using. I haven't changed anything on my code. I only updated to Xcode 5.1 today and got these warnings

Comment: arm64 armv7 armv7s ok here it is. But is this only for 64-bit? does this mean I can only support 64-bit devices?

Comment: No. it is also support for 32-bit also because armv7 and 7s for 32-bit . I think, now there is no arch for 64-bit(xcode 5.0.2) only.

Comment: Because if you run this code in 64-bit environment, will give warning. See **Use Data Types Consistently** topic in this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013501-CH3-SW14

Answer (score 2):

The actual type of `NSUInteger` is different depending on whether you compile for 32 bit or 64 bit. Therefore, whatever format you use, you will get a warning, either in the 32 bit build or in the 64 bit build. Solution is quite easy:

```
NSString *viewName_ = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myGreatView%lu", (unsigned long) (currentTagLoadedOnView-99)];
```

`NSUInteger` can be cast to `unsigned long` without loss of information, both on 32 bit and 64 bit systems.